# @font-face displaying a font but not the other

Tags: css, path, font-face

I have a simple one-page layout, all HTML + CSS basically(will add some js soon but it's not there at the moment).

Baiscally i have this:

```
/* Cambo */

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'CamboRegular';
    src: url('font/cambo/Cambo-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/cambo/Cambo-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/cambo/Cambo-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/cambo/Cambo-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/cambo/Cambo-Regular-webfont.svg#CamboRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }

/* Source Sans Pro */

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular';
    src: url('font/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.svg#SourceSansProRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }
```

When i use font-family: 'Cambo Regular'; **it works**, but when i try to choose a font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular'; **the font is not being loaded** on any browser i try.

The original path for the fonts in the website folders was url('../assets/fonts/ --> rest copied from FontSquirrel

Since i noticed none of the two worked i moved them inside the folder where the css are so i have

main folder(with index pointing at the css folder)/assets/css(with my css)/font(with the two fonts folders inside)

Why is this not working? Am i missing something while declaring the path? If CamboRegular shouldn't work too but it's displaying just fine both on Windows and Mac on any browser.

**QUICK EDIT!**

I changed the path to a totally wrong one and it displays the basic page font.
I think the font is being loaded but it looks "bolder" than it should be. If you watch the design in Photoshop and then on the page it looks different(i made the design so i know it wasn't stretched or something) but CamboRegular is still looking and acting as it should.

**Here's the image to show the problem**

http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2671/nnqu.jpg

The CSS for the

the grey text is included in is pretty simple too

```
p {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular';
    font-size: 16px; }
```

And here's the one for the top menu(not shown in this image) with the CamboRegular correctly working

```
h1 { 
color: #494949;
font-family: 'CamboRegular';
font-size: 48px;
text-align: center; }
```

As you can see it's nothing fancy but still, one's working the other isn't.

Comment: Do you have a live link for this issue?

Comment: Yes i'm uploading an image right now in my question!